# How to parse "30-06-2017 07:55 pm" in Date in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, jsp-tags

I have below bootstrap datepicker element in my `JSP form`:

```
<tr>
<td>
   <form:label path="bookStartTime" title="Booking Start Time" class="control-label">Booking Start Time
   <font color="red">&nbsp;&nbsp;*</font>
   </form:label>
</td>
<td>
   <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
   <form:input path="bookStartTime" title="Booking Start time" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm am/pm" /> 
   <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
   </span>
   </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

I have used below javascript to select timestamp in this format `DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm a`:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({format: 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm a'});
    $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(new Date());
});
```

Now I need to compare the selected date from datepicker with many dates that come from backend (database) having same format.

The problem is that in javascript I am unable to parse this `DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm a` date format. 
I tried using many ways and moment.js also but have found no success after lot of time.

It would be great if you can provide some links/references or solution if possible. Thanks!

Comment: What does the 'a' in the data format stand for?

Comment: @Raunaqss it is for `am/pm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a date string in format `DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm a` the best option would be to use regex, get all the numbers from the string in the correct order and pass them to `Date()` constructor to get a date object.

For example:

```
var x = '30-06-2017 20:50 pm';
// returns array of matched 2 and 4 digit numbers
var arr = x.match(/([0-9]{2,4})/g); 
// arr equals ['30', '06', '2017', '20', '50']
var dateObj = new Date(arr[2], arr[1], arr[0], arr[3], arr[4]);
```

That's all, `dateObj` is what you're looking for. Hope this helps.

Comment: This would be great if it works. I have one question though. Mine is not `24 hour` format. It is `12 hour` format and so at the end it has `am/pm`. So how to get that last `a` ? Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: I tested your solution. Worked fine but only one problem: it's unable to catch that `a` and so losing track of `am/pm`

Comment: @RDhaval just a moment, I'll update my solution to accommodate the am/pm 12 hour format.

Comment: and another problem is It converts `Jul 30, 2017 GMT+0530` to `SUNDAY` while it is `Friday` today :P

Comment: I solved this "sunday" problem. I passed `month-1` like **Date(arr[2], arr[1]-1, arr[0], arr[3], arr[4]);**  to get `Fri JUN 30 `.

Comment: @RDhaval glad you solved it and got my mistake too :)

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the date string manually, thus you should use the Date constructor with the year, month and day arguments:

```
// parse a date in yyyy-mm-dd format
function parseDate(date) {
  var parts = date.split('-');
  /* new Date(year, month [, day [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]]) */
  var newdate = new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]);
  return newdate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the more correct solution from @Raunaqss's answer.

```
    var x=$("#bookStartTime").val();
    var arr = x.match(/([0-9]{2,4})/g);
    if(x!=null && x!="undefined"){
        var splitX=x.split('');
        var ampm= splitX[splitX.length-2]+splitX[splitX.length-1];
    }
    if(ampm=='pm'){
        arr[3]=parseInt(arr[3])+12;
    }
    var dateObj = new Date(arr[2], arr[1]-1, arr[0], arr[3], arr[4], 0, 0);
    alert(dateObj);
```

I just checked if there is `pm` at the end of the timestamp value. If it is there then just added `12` to the `hours`.